# HTML5 video set currentTime not work on Samsung Smart TV

Tags: vue.js, html5-video, tizen, tizen-web-app

i creating a html5 video element on want to set the position of the video to a specific. If i open the index.html in chrome or running it on the Tizen Web Simulator Applocation its works fine. But if i deploy the application on the smart tv it does not work at reset the currentTime always to the starttime.

```
video id="video" src="{externalResource}" ref="videoplayer" @loadedmetadata="initplayScreenProgressControls" @timeupdate="updateProgressTimer()"></video>

initplayScreenProgressControls(){

  document.getElementById('video').currentTime = 200;
  document.getElementById('video').play();

},
```

So why does it work on the emulator and the browser but not in the physical device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem was not the HTML5 video in tizen. The problem was the source where the video was loaded from. Before i setup a fastify webserver with fastify static and i cant figured out why but if the video was loaded from fastify static the player cant set the current time.
now i loaded the video directly from a nginx server and it work fine.

Answer (score 0):

What is tizen version? (3.0, 4.0, 5.0....)

I believe that you played HTML5 video with URL (not MSE), was it?

Seeking may fail if player can't recognize the duration of media(video).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).